# Build has_many :through for new Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through

I might be doing this wrong overall, but maybe someone will be able to chirp in and help out.

**Problem**:

I want to be able to build a relationship on an unsaved Object, such that this would work:

```
v = Video.new
v.title = "New Video"
v.actors.build(:name => "Jonny Depp")
v.save!
```

To add to this, these will be generated through a custom method, which I'm attempting to modify to work, that does the following:

```
v = Video.new
v.title = "Interesting cast..."
v.actors_list = "Jonny Depp, Clint Eastwood, Rick Moranis"
v.save
```

This method looks like this in video.rb

```
def actors_list=value
  #Clear for existing videos
  self.actors.clear

  value.split(',').each do |actorname|
    if existing = Actor.find_by_name(actorname.strip)
      self.actors << existing
    else
      self.actors.build(:name => actorname.strip)
    end
  end
end
```

What I expect

```
v.actors.map(&:name)
=> ["Jonny Depp", "Clint Eastwood", "Rick Moranis"]
```

Unfortunatey, these tactics neither create an Actor nor the association. Oh yeah, you might ask me for that:

in video.rb

```
has_many :actor_on_videos
has_many :actors, :through => :actor_on_videos

accepts_nested_attributes_for :actors
```

I've also tried modifying the `actors_list=` method as such:

```
def actors_list=value
  #Clear for existing videos
  self.actors.clear

  value.split(',').each do |actorname|
    if existing = Actor.find_by_name(actorname.strip)
      self.actors << existing
    else
      self.actors << Actor.create!(:name => actorname.strip)
    end
  end
end
```

And it creates the Actor, but I'd rather not create the Actor if the Video fails on saving.

So am I approaching this wrong? Or have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :actor_on_videos
  has_many :actors, :through => :actor_on_videos

  attr_accessor :actors_list
  after_save    :save_actors

  def actors_list=names
    (names.presence || "").split(",").uniq.map(&:strip).tap do |new_list|
      @actors_list = new_list if actors_list_changes?(new_list)
    end
  end

  def actors_list_changes?(new_list)
    new_record? or 
      (actors.count(:conditions => {:name => new_list}) != new_list.size)
  end

  # save the actors in after save.
  def save_actors
    return true if actors_list.blank?
    # create the required names
    self.actors = actors_list.map {|name| Actor.find_or_create_by_name(name)}
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works wonderfully. Threw in some edit suggestions for where I had to make changes to get it to work

Comment: I thought you'd be able to see them with your rep, sorry. I'm not up there myself yet. Here you go >> http://pastebin.com/2LaXGe4G

Comment: @KyleMacey, I have changed the position of `uniq` and `strip`. Also, I have reverted the changes you have made to the  `save_actors` method. It should work with the original code. What was the error you encountered?

Comment: actors_list isn't defined... I thought that's why you were defining it as @actors_list, so it could be used in the other methods... Also, if a model is created without being passed an actors_list (mostly for when i was testing in console), actors_list would be undefined in save_actors, because actors_list was never called to define it

Comment: The `actor_list` attribute accessor will work even when `@actor_list` variable is not set. It will return `nil`. The `empty?` method does the `nil` and `emptiness` checks, so there is no need to perform the `nil` check again. You should not access the attribute variables out side the `setter` and `getter` functions as it breaks the data encapsulation rules.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9028/discussion-between-kyle-macey-and-kandadaboggu)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a child to an object with no id. You will need to store the actors in your new video object and save those records after the video has been saved and has an id.